# Do function with the following property have special name?

Tags: notation, terminology, category-theory

I'm writing "*a structure preserving surjection*" way too much when I need to refer a function of the following property:

$$ Y \subseteq Z, X \subseteq Z. g: Z \to A, g \text{ is some fixed function}.$$
$$ \phi : X \to Y, \phi \text{ is a surjection, and } g(\phi(x)) = g(x).$$

Would a category theorist frown if I call $\phi$ a epimorphism?

Comment: I expect they would object mightily, unless the functions with this property are right-cancellable.

Comment: Regular people might object too ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind making up names (obviously, make sure you define them prominently), then here are two ideas:

- The preimage under $g$ of each point in $g(Y)$ contains two points, one of which is mapped to the other by $\phi$. Perhaps you could call $\phi$ a preimage map.
- The image of $X\subset Z$ under $g$ is invariant under $\phi$. Perhaps you could call $\phi$ an invariance, or equivariance.

(I like the second idea better than the first. In fact, I see some nonce uses of *invariance* in what appears to be this sense on Google Books ([example](http://books.google.com/books?id=fHXWgoJu9UoC&pg=PA7&dq=an-invariance)).)